# Angular2 event called only on SOME of the elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, submit

So i have a Modal Component with a form in it, this component is used for both creating an entry to the DB and editing an existing one.

It has a subscription option to the `onSubmit` event, which is being executed on a successful submit.

What happens for some reason is that some of this component's element subscription executes and some won't, and it looks like those on the "create-mode" will and those on the "edit-mode" wont.

### Code Section

CreateOrUpdateTransactionComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'create-update-transaction',
    templateUrl: './CreateOrUpdateTransaction.html',
    providers: [AccountTransactionsService]
})
export class CreateOrUpdateTransactionComponent {
    closeResult: string;
    modalRef: NgbModalRef;

    @Input() transaction: Transaction = new Transaction();
    @Input() isCreate: boolean;
    @Output() onSubmit: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
                private transactionsService: AccountTransactionsService) {}

    sendTransaction(): void{
        let localModalRef = this.modalRef;
        this.transactionsService.createOrUpdateTransaction(this.transaction, (isSuccessful)=>{
            if (isSuccessful) {
                this.onSubmit.emit(); //<--- The problem is here
                localModalRef.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <caption>Account Transactions</caption>
    <thead>
        // Omitted thead
    </thead>
    <template let-transaction ngFor [ngForOf]="accountTransactions" let-i="index">
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#'+i">
            // Omitted <td>s
            <td> //<----These updateTransactions() are not being executed
                <create-update-transaction [isCreate]="false" [transaction]="transaction" (onSubmit)="updateTransactions()"></create-update-transaction>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <div class="container collapse" [attr.id]="i">
            // some content
        </div>
    </template>
</table>
<create-update-transaction [isCreate]="true" (onSubmit)="updateTransactions()"></create-update-transaction>
//<---- This updateTransactions() successfully executes
```

### Notice

- If I only display one row in the table not using `ngFor` (keeping the call to the back-end to update the DB), it works perfectly fine.

Any idea why would this happen?

Thanks in advance!

### Update1

Debugging i could notice that when on the create-mode the `this.onSubmit.observers` is an array with one observer and on the edit-mode its an array with 0 observers, so thats the problem. any idea why?

### Update2

Debugging again and found that the `this` in `this.transactionsService.createOrUpdateTransaction...` is fine and its' `onSubmit.observers` contains 1 observer, before reaching the callback's code, in which the `this.onSubmit.observers` is an array of 0 observers

AccountTransactionsService:

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountTransactionsService{
    private loggedBankAccount: number;
    private queryObservable: ObservableQuery;

    constructor(private userManagingService: UserManagingService) {
        this.loggedBankAccount = userManagingService.getLoggedBankAccountNumber();

        this.queryAccountTransactions();
    }

    queryAccountTransactions(): void{
        this.queryObservable = // querying the back-end
    }

    createOrUpdateTransaction(transaction: Transaction, callback: (isSuccessfull: boolean) => void): void{
        let isSuccessful: boolean = false;

        client.mutate(/*inserting the backend*/).then((graphQLResult) => {
            const { errors, data } = graphQLResult;

            if (data) {
                console.log('got data', data);
                isSuccessful = true;
            }

            if (errors) {
                console.log('got some GraphQL execution errors', errors);
            }

            callback(isSuccessful);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('there was an error sending the query', error);
            callback(isSuccessful);
        });
    }

    getAccountTransactions(): ObservableQuery{
        return this.queryObservable;
    }
}
```

### Notice

- If i just execute the callback give to the `AccountTransactionService.createOrUpdateTransaction` (removing the call to the back-end to actually update the DB) it works perfectly fine and all the subscribers to this `onSubmit` event are being called.

### `this` Console image

[image]

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the quick reply. as you can see the ModalComponent has two optional `@Input` -> `isCreated & transaction`, if they are passed it behaves like in "edit-mode" which already has some data and displays it in the Modal's form for editing. Not passing these inputs will keep the inputs of the form empty for creating

Comment: Put `debugger;` front of `this.onSubmit.emit();` and check it in browser console.

Comment: @yurzui Doing as u suggested i could notice that when on the create-mode the `this.onSubmit.observers` is an array with one observer and on the edit-mode its an array with 0 observers, so thats the problem. aby idea why?

Comment: Can you share more code. i.e `CreateOrUpdateTransaction.html`. Where do you open modal?

Comment: @yurzui Added your request, this is just a bunch of `<input>`s and `<button>`s

Comment: Can you reproduce it here https://plnkr.co/edit/9rWX3T4tfhN4NZt05D9O?p=preview?

Comment: @yurzui i had no success in reproducing the bug in Plnkr, it worked perfectly fine there. so i went back to debugging and found that the `this` in `this.transactionsService.createOrUpdateTransaction...` is fine and its' `onSubmit.observers` contains 1 observer, before reaching the callback's code

Comment: Before this line? `this.transactionsService.createOrUpdateTransaction`?

Comment: Share please your service

Comment: I will in a moment, but i think this is a problem of scopes, like for the same reason i had to create a `localModalRef` since `this.modalRef` is undefined inside the callback

Comment: Put `var self = this` front of `this.transactionsService.createOrUpdateTransaction`  and then inside callback use `self.onsubmit.emit()`. How do you call callback inside `createOrUpdateTransaction` function?

Comment: @yurzui nope, not a scopes problem, added the `AccountTransactionsService` service code

Comment: Try to print `this` inside callback. I still cant reproduce it

Comment: @yurzui for some reason `console.log(this)` prints `undefined undefined`, while debugging it displays it normally, with the `onSubmit` and any other property.

Comment: What is the `client`? Where is it from?

Comment: `client` is just an instance of my application as a `ApolloClient` for querying a graphql `apollo-server`. added an image of the console for the `this`

Comment: @yurzui save me ♥

Comment: Maybe you can upload a minimal copy of your project to github. Only client code without server part

Comment: @yurzui Actually im working for a guy and this is a private repository, something specific you think missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the case was that the data the `ngFor` is bound to was being replaced by a new instance as I updated the backend, hence, it rerendered it's child Components causing reinitializing (destory + init) of them, which made the instance of the Component to be overwritten.

In order to solve this issue i have changed the querying of the `accountTransaction` to be only one time querying, on initializing of the parent component, and never `refetch`ing again (which triggers the rerendering).

Im displaying to the client the changes only if they succeeded on the server side, and if they failed i use a backup of the data, so the client is kept update of the real state of the server WITHOUT `refetch`ing

### For the future lookers to come:

The key to the problem was that the Parent Component's `*ngFor` depended on data that was changing in the Child Components, causing reinitializing of the `*ngFor` (the Child Components) **BEFORE** finishing executions of the Child Components methods.

Hope it'll be helpful to somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `null` as a parameter :

`this.onSubmit.emit(null);`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not produce any change, could you please explain?

Comment: If you don`t use any parameter, this error : **Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target** will be appeared.

Comment: I've been using the `emit` method with no parameters for a long time and everything worked fine actually